# Monitor numbering correct in Windows 11 but wrong in applications

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, windows-11, numbering

I have a laptop with two screens built in. I also have two external monitors via an USB docking. According to Windows the main screen of the laptop is #1, the subscreen on the laptop #2, the external monitor to the left #3 and the external monitor to the right #4. Exactly as I expect.

Somehow however, applications on this machine get a faulty numbering from Windows. Numbers 3 and 4 are switched. In the applications #3 is to the right and #4 is to the left. Not a major issue but irritating nontheless.

Has anybody an idea how I can change this?